# How to package Maven 2 generated-classes by Cobertura?

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage, cobertura

i have a Maven 2 project setup which nicely packages a war file using a `pom.xml` now i want to introduce Cobertura to that. I can succesfully instrument the classes but when i want to package the instrumented classes and deploy them to my jboss server the wrong files are being packaged.

My target tree looks like this:

```
\target
\target\classes --> contains non instrumented classes
\target\cobertura
\target\generated-classes
\target\generated-classes\cobertura --> contains the instrumented classes
```

Whenever i try to package my war it packages the \target\classes and not the \target\generated-classes\cobertura is there a way to force the packaging to use the files which are located in \target\generated-classes\cobertura ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common use case for the cobertura plugin (to my knowledge) is to run unit tests on instrumented classes and generate a report on test coverage. If I wanted the instrumented classes in a war-file, I'd try with the assembly plugin.

Comment: The challenge is that the project contains several webservices for which no unit tests are written. So the deployed war file must be loaded inside the container to enable the webservices. By just calling the webservice i would like to get an idea on what code is touched when calling webservice code.